# File Tree Structure into NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsfilemanager, property-list

I'm trying to read a full File/Folder Structure (starting from a given Folder) into an `NSDictionary` (with a `NSArray`s,etc), like this :

Let's say starting folder is : /Users/some-user/some-path

We go in there and list all folders/subfolders/files

A/

- file_a.txt
- file_b.txt
- subfolder/

  - file_c.txt

B/

- etc...

What I want is to convert this file structure (probably using enumerators and `NSFileManager`) into an `NSDictionary` like :

```
<key>folder</key>
<string>A</string>
<key>values</key>
<array>
       <dict>
             <key>file</key>
             <string>file_a.txt</string>
             <key>url</key>
             <string>/Users/some-user/some-path/A/file_a.txt</string>
       </dict>
       <dict>
             <key>file</key>
             <string>file_b.txt</string>
             <key>url</key>
             <string>/Users/some-user/some-path/A/file_b.txt</string>
       </dict>
       <dict>
             <key>folder</key>
             <string>subfolder</string>
             <key>values</key>
             <array>
                       ...
             </array>
       </dict>

</array>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I see that you have tagged the question with `nsfilemanager`.  `nsfilemanager` has all the methods you need for this task, so I'm not sure what else you need to know.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, I managed to do it (I'll post the full answer later); however, I'm still having an issue checking if a path is a folder... could you help me with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736696/how-to-check-if-path-in-nsstring-represents-a-folder-or-bundle-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the **working** result :

To check if a `path` is a Directory/Package/Bundle, etc :

```
- (BOOL)isDir:(NSString*)path
{
    BOOL isDir;
    if (([[NSFileManager defaultManager]
        fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) || 
        ([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] isFilePackageAtPath:path]))
              return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

The actual function (using recursion) :

```
- (NSArray*)getContents:(NSString*)path {

NSError* err = nil;
NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&err];

NSMutableArray* conts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

for (NSString* c in files)
{
    NSDictionary* d;

    NSString* p = [d stringByAppendingPathComponent:d];

    if (![self isDir:p])
    {
        d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           c,@"name",
                           p,@"url", nil];
    }
    else
    {
        d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
             c,@"group",
             p,@"entries", nil];
    }

    [conts addObject:d];
}

return conts;
}
```

Comment: not using any recursion... and also your code doesn't compile... you are adding a dictionary "d" as a path component??