# How to iterate through the folder hierarchy in a web server in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm a newbie to ios programming. I have some files and folders in my web server. I need to iterate through all the folders and sub-folders in the web server and store it in  NSDictionary. I found  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735622/file-tree-structure-into-nsdictionary/)  which gets the folder structure from a local file system. I need something similar to this from my web server. Appreciate you help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should walk through the directory on your server first.

Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5421671/889538

PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750406/889538

Or some-language else.

Then your iOS App can request the target folder hierarchy from your server, maybe in JSON format.

Now, [convert JSON data into NSDictionary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606444/how-do-i-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary-in-ios5).

Comment: Hi Jason Lee, I should walk through the directory and where should I store the result and in what format. Can I call php/python script in ios programs? Please advise, as I'm very new to ios programming. Thanks.

Comment: @John It's irrelevant to iOS. It's your server script's responsibilty.  Do you know how to send a GET-request to the server? Like visit the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15194217/889538